# TF transfert learning: google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 162:19

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I trying to learn transfert learning with tensorflow and ssd inception.

I have my csv files,the TF records and the label_map.pbtxt (with 1 categorie)
after downloading the files : .config file, the ssd_inception_v2_coco model i have an error the moment i run the code.

I had to delete the comments in the top of the config file.

Now i have a new error :

> raise self.ParseError('Expected string but found: %r' % (text,))
> google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 162:19 : '  label_map_path: “custom_training/records/label_map.pbtxt”': Expected string but found: '“'

The code i run is :
`python model_main.py --alsologtostderr --model_dir=custom_training/training --pipeline_config_path=custom_training/training/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.config`

I not sure to understand where that error come from. I check my folders and it's ok.
It's look like it is the label file.

I made some research and i find something here :https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/451906e4e82f19712455066c1b27e2a6ba71b1dd/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py

at the line 147 we find this :

```
def load_labelmap(path):
  """Loads label map proto.
  Args:
    path: path to StringIntLabelMap proto text file.
  Returns:
    a StringIntLabelMapProto
  """
  with tf.io.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
    label_map_string = fid.read()
    label_map = string_int_label_map_pb2.StringIntLabelMap()
    try:
      text_format.Merge(label_map_string, label_map)
    except text_format.ParseError:
      label_map.ParseFromString(label_map_string)
  _validate_label_map(label_map)
  return label_map
```

But i totaly don't know where to use it...

So my first question is : am i rigth that is the rigth method?

The seconde : Where to use that code? Inside my config file? At the moment where i generate my TFrecord?

As you see i'm totally lost :D

FI: i'm using Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 64bit. I only used file from Tensorflow's github.
I try with another model : mobilenet_V2_1.14_224 and i have the same error...
Using python 3.7 in an env and protobuff/Pycocotools/Cython

Thanks for the help. I hope I'll be able to help back.

So ode

***Edit : i find the solution.... it was dumb.
In my config file i miss type the path....
Sorry, and i hope this edit can help someone :)***